# Python class method runs much slower than identical function

Tags: python, function, class, methods

I have the following class:

```
class MyKMeans:
    def __init__(self, max_iter = 300):
        self.max_iter = max_iter
        # Directly access 
        self.centroids = None
        self.clusters = None

    def fit(self, X, k):
        """
        
        """

        # each point is assigned to a cluster
        clusters = np.zeros(X.shape[0])

        # select k random centroids
        random_idxs = np.random.choice(len(X), size=k, replace=False)
        centroids = X[random_idxs, :]

        # iterate until no change occurs in centroids
        while True: 
            # for each point
            for i, point in enumerate(X):
                min_d = float('inf')

                # find the closest centroid to the point
                for idx, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
                    d = euclidean_dist(centroid, point)
                    if d < min_d:
                        min_d = d
                        clusters[i] = idx

                # update the new centroids by averaging the points in each cluster
                new_centroids = pd.DataFrame(X).groupby(by=clusters).mean().values
            
            # if the centroids didn't change, then stop
            if np.count_nonzero(centroids-new_centroids) == 0:
                break
            # otherwise, update the centroids
            else:
                centroids = new_centroids

        self.centroids = centroids
        self.clusters = clusters
```

and run it using

```
k = 4
kmeans = MyKMeans()
kmeans.fit(X, k)
centroids, clusters = kmeans.centroids, kmeans.clusters
```

However, this takes usually 5 seconds to complete running. On the other hand, if I move the method to a new function,

```
def fit(X, k):
    """
    
    """

    # each point is assigned to a cluster
    clusters = np.zeros(X.shape[0])

    # select k random centroids
    random_idxs = np.random.choice(len(X), size=k, replace=False)
    centroids = X[random_idxs, :]

    # iterate until no change occurs in centroids
    while True: 
        # for each point
        for i, point in enumerate(X):
            min_d = float('inf')

            # find the closest centroid to the point
            for idx, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
                d = euclidean_dist(centroid, point)
                if d < min_d:
                    min_d = d
                    clusters[i] = idx

            # update the new centroids by averaging the points in each cluster
            new_centroids = pd.DataFrame(X).groupby(by=clusters).mean().values
        
        # if the centroids didn't change, then stop
        if np.count_nonzero(centroids-new_centroids) == 0:
            break
        # otherwise, update the centroids
        else:
            centroids = new_centroids

        return centroids, clusters
```

and get the same variables by calling `centroids, clusters = fit(X, k)`, the runtime is around 0.5-1 second which is a big difference.

Is there a reason why simply having a class method instead of a function causes such a big difference in runtime, and is there any way to improve the runtime while still being able to use the class?

Comment: The first version has a `while True:` loop that will run some number of times when the function is called.  The second version's corresponding loop runs only one time, because you've put a `return` statement inside it.  Before comparing run times, you really need to verify that both versions actually produce the same result!

Comment: Your original question had `self.centroids` etc. in the method code, which you later edited into `centroids`. Have you benchmarked again, with the self-less code? Because that single change should have sped up your code (after `return` is extracted from the loop, of course)

Comment: Apologies for the mistake. After fixing the code again, if the problem is still there, should I make a new question or edit this one?

Comment: You can just edit it. But in that case it makes no sense to me... What could make a classmethod slower is accessing `self.variable` instead of `variable` because lookups take time. But that is in nearly all cases negligible

Answer (score 2):

The return statement in your non-class version is inside of the while loop so it exits the loop early.